# Delete rows with specific values by keeping first and last row of dataframe

Tags: r, conditional-statements, delete-row

I have a dataframe which made by appending similar dataframes. 
sample file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwswfhTezOETWmpPakpGOUl0V0E

```
Lat Lon Species BottomDepth RunStatus
6023.9796   518.5393        NA   TowStarted 
6023.9796   518.5393     Cucumber   25    
6023.9796   518.5393     Cucumber   25     
6023.9796   518.5392     Chank  25     
6023.9797   518.5392        NA   TowStarted 
6023.9797   518.5392        NA   TowStopped 
6023.9797   518.5392     Cucumber   29     
6023.9797   518.5392     Chank  29     
6023.9797   518.5392     Chank  29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Sea Urchine    29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Sea Urchine    29     
6023.9797   518.5391        NA   TowStarted 
6023.9797   518.5391        NA   TowStopped 
6023.9797   518.5391     Sea Urchine    29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Sea Urchine    29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Sea Urchine    29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Sea Urchine    29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Cucumber   29     
6023.9797   518.5391        NA   TowStarted 
6023.9797   518.5391        NA   TowStopped 
6023.9797   518.5391     Cucumber   29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Cucumber   35     
6023.9797   518.5391     Cucumber   35     
6023.9797   518.5391     Cucumber   35     
6023.9797   518.5391     Cucumber   35     
6023.9797   518.5391     Chank  35     
6023.9797   518.5391        NA   TowStopped
```

I need to keep first and last rows. but need to delete rows with RunStatus=="TowStarted" and RunStatus=="TowStopped".

```
mf<- read.csv("C:/Video_sledge/Output/merge.csv")
mf1 <-mf[ !grepl("TowStarted", mf$RunStatus) , ]
mf2 <-mf1[ !grepl("TowStopped", mf1$RunStatus) , ]
```

but this code deletes first and last rows.

How delete middle rows with test condition (RunStatus=="TowStarted" and RunStatus=="TowStopped") while keeping first and last rows?

expected output as follows

```
Lat Lon Species BottomDepth RunStatus
6023.9796   518.5393        NA   TowStarted 
6023.9796   518.5393     Cucumber   25    
6023.9796   518.5393     Cucumber   25     
6023.9796   518.5392     Chank  25     
6023.9797   518.5392     Cucumber   29     
6023.9797   518.5392     Chank  29     
6023.9797   518.5392     Chank  29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Sea Urchine    29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Sea Urchine    29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Sea Urchine    29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Sea Urchine    29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Sea Urchine    29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Sea Urchine    29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Cucumber   29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Cucumber   29     
6023.9797   518.5391     Cucumber   35     
6023.9797   518.5391     Cucumber   35     
6023.9797   518.5391     Cucumber   35     
6023.9797   518.5391     Cucumber   35     
6023.9797   518.5391     Chank  35     
6023.9797   518.5391        NA   TowStopped
```

Comment: Please add a reproducible example and expected output

Comment: I have added sample set and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mf[c(1,which(!(mf$RunStatus %in% c(" TowStarted "," TowStopped "))),nrow(mf)),]
```

Comment: Warning message:
In c(1, nrow(mf)) | !(mf$RunStatus %in% c("TowStarted", "TowStopped")) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df %>% 
  filter(!(RunStatus %in% c("TowStarted", "TowStopped")) | row_number() %in% c(1, nrow(df)))
```

I tested it on other data and it worked.

Comment: Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'RunStatus' not found

Answer (score 0):

```
mf<- read.csv("C:/Video_sledge/Output/merge.csv")
frow <- mf[1,]
mf1 <-mf[ !grepl("TowStarted", mf$RunStatus) , ]
mf2 <-mf1[ !grepl("TowStopped", mf1$RunStatus) , ]
lrow <- mf[nrow(mf),]
f <-rbind(frow,mf2,lrow)
```

this code gives me above output. but I think someone has a better solution.